# How to get multiple regex on same string in scala

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

My requirement is to get multiple regex patterns in a given String.

```
"<a href=\"https://page1.google.com/ab-cd/ABCDEF\”>Hello</a> hiiii <a href=\"https://page2.yahoo.com/gr\”>page</a><img src=\"https://image01.google.com/gr/content/attachment/987654321\” alt=\”demo image\”></a><a href=\"https://page3.google.com/hr\">"
```

With this below code:

```
val p = Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*?)\"")
    val m = p.matcher(str)
    while(m.find()){
      println(m.group(1))
    }
```

I am getting output:

```
https://page1.google.com/ab-cd/ABCDEF
https://page2.yahoo.com/gr
https://page3.google.com/hr
```

With change in Pattern:

```
val p = Pattern.compile("img src=\"(.*?)\"")
```

I am getting output:

```
https://image01.google.com/gr/content/attachment/987654321
```

But with Pattern:

```
val p = Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*?)\"|img src=\"(.*?)\"")
```

I am getting output:

```
https://page1.google.com/ab-cd/ABCDEF
https://page2.yahoo.com/gr
Null
https://page3.google.com/hr
```

Please let me know, how to get multiple regex pattern or is their any other easy way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
val rx = "(?:href|img src)=\"(.*?)\"".r
val results = rx.findAllMatchIn(s).map(_ group 1)
// println(results.mkString(", ")) prints:
//  https://page1.google.com/ab-cd/ABCDEF, 
//  https://page2.yahoo.com/gr, 
//  https://image01.google.com/gr/content/attachment/987654321, 
//  https://page3.google.com/hr
```

See the [Scala demo](https://rextester.com/PRBR59934)

**Details**

- `(?:href|img src)=\"(.*?)\"` matches either `href` or `img src`, then a `="`, and then captures any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible into Group 1, and then a `"` is matched
- With `.findAllIn`, you get all matches, then `.map(_ group 1)` only fetches Group 1 values.